# LinkedIn API "Follow a Company" using IN.API.Raw

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I am working with LinkedIn API and trying to call for "Start Follow a Company". My API request is as follows

```
var url = 'people/~/following/companies',            
    body = {
        company: {
            id: '1337'
        }
    };

    IN.API.Raw()            
        .url(url)
        .method("POST")
        .body(JSON.stringify(body))            
        .result(function (result) {
           console.log(result);
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

But,it isnt working. Kindly help me out with this.

Regards, 
Bhavika Patel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a reference for others, there is the answer posted to the same question on the [LinkedIn Developer's Forums](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/following-company-javascript-api#comment-13275).

Comment: Seems to be a dead link (not surprising given the time frame)